# Find the index of the array--java

Tags: java, arrays, search, location

I got one code which is an array that can hold up to 8 randomly generated integer values between
number to number; Next, it will ask the user to input a number.after input, it will find the location of the array where the number is input by the user.Next, as soon as the first number in the array matches the input number,the algorithm will stop and display the location. In contrast, if the value cannot be found, simply display no found.

here is the code;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class q3_2 {
static Random generator = new Random();
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args){
int[] number = new int [8];
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
for (int idx = 0 ; idx < number.length ; ++idx){
int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)+1; 
System.out.print(randomInt + " ");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("your input please: " );
int inputInt;
inputInt = input.nextInt();
int idxToFind = -1;
for (int idx = 0 ; idx < number.length ; ++idx){
idxToFind= idx;
break;
}
System.out.println(inputInt + " is on the " + idxToFind);
```

here is the output

[image]

by right it should display the 7 is on 1;but it showing 0. i'm not sure where is the mistake i make. appreciate your advice and suggestion.

Comment: You input an integer into `inputInt`.  Where do you do anything with `inputInt` after that?

Comment: You have absolutely no conditional logic in your loops, how do you expect to find a number if you aren't comparing anything to it?

Comment: Please indent your code. It's very difficult to read like this.

Answer (score 1):

initialize your array (pointed out by @AJB) AND add conditional logic

```
for (int idx = 0 ; idx < number.length ; ++idx){
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(50)+1; 
    number[idx] = randomInt;//INITIALIZED
    System.out.print(randomInt + " ");
}
```

...

```
for (int idx = 0 ; idx < number.length ; ++idx){
    if (number[idx] == idxToFind) {
        idxToFind= idx;
        break;
    }
}
```

alternatively, you can use `indexOf`, but you should do more research before asking this kind of question. It looks like you are taking an easy way out of a homework assignment.

Comment: Rafael; thanks for the advice; now i able to overcome my problem after the research(is a lot) and testing; which is debug, debug and debug...